# How to I set min and max value for Input with type='datetime-local'?

Tags: mysql, datetime, input

I have an input field that should send a value to mysql and I want to set max and min values to predict a date range the user can select from.

This input is a datetime-local field, because I want him to select the time as well.

I know how to set it for date, but can't get it to work. Maybe I miss a thing?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqxvdyn8/)

```
  <label>This is datetime-local</label>

<input type='datetime-local' min='2017-06-14 00:00:00' max='2017-06-16 00:00:00'>

  <label>This is date</label>

<input type='date' name="date" min="2017-06-14" max="2017-06-16">
```

Comment: ok, i guess i am missing the T between date and time. How do I get this in my mysql query?

Comment: I got it. I simple use a T in between my select. `DATE_FORMAT(date_arrival, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i")`

Answer (score 9):

In spite of what is declared [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#min) I made it work adding seconds too, like yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="start-date" min="2021-06-07T14:47:57" />
```

I needed min input to be "today" so with JS:

```
let dateInput = document.getElementById("start-date");
dateInput.min = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,new Date().toISOString().lastIndexOf(":"));
```

Then calendar won't let you pass that min date. You can apply same code for max attribute.

Comment: Nice tweaking/hacking to find the datetime!

Answer (score 5):

Example with min and max values

```
<input
    type="datetime-local"
    className="form-control mt-2"
    name="start_date"
    min="2011-02-20T20:20"
    max="2031-02-20T20:20"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a hard time finding an answer about this using PHP. But I just discovered an answer and I just want to share the code that I've came up using PHP. I know this question is too old.

```
<input type="datetime-local" min="<?=date('Y-m-d\Th:i')?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that in ISO string last 8 characters are always `:XX.XXXz`, this may be more elegant:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8)
```