# HTML5 | Datepicker only 5 days ahead in future

Tags: html, datepicker

I have a date picker on my web app, I only want the user to be able to click on a date between today and over 5 days (so today the date is 2020-06-02, the user should only be able to click on dates between 2020-06-02 and 2020-06-06).
I have looked for solutions but the only thing I found was using a min and a max, but those do not work for me.
Has anyone an idea how I can achieve this?

This is my code:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="name">Locatie: </label><br />
        <input type="text" id="naam" asp-for="Locatie" />
        <label for="Datetime">Datum: </label>
        <input value="05-19-2020T12:00" min="05-19-2020T12:00" type="datetime-local" id="DateTime" asp-for="DatumTijd" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The min and the value both do not work, but it is what I have tried so thats why I am showing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `minDate` and `maxDate`:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0, 
        maxDate: "+5D" 
    });
});
```

Comment: Here's a similar question which is already solved.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585148/how-to-i-set-min-and-max-value-for-input-with-type-datetime-local